# Rsyslog remote and local log

Tags: linux, centos, rsyslog

I got a little problem, i try to use **rsyslog** for both local and remote log from a server.
Since i use this configuration to get the remote log, my local logs are empty.

Any help please ? is it the `*.*` wrong on the remote log sophos.log ?

```
-rw-------.  1 root   root              0 28 juil. 14:51 spooler
-rw-------.  1 root   root              0 28 juil. 14:51 secure
-rw-------.  1 root   root              0 28 juil. 14:51 messages
-rw-------.  1 root   root              0 28 juil. 14:51 maillog
-rw-------.  1 root   root              0 28 juil. 14:51 cron
```

Configuration for the remote log coming the firewall box

```
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")
$AllowedSender TCP, 10.1.0.69

$template RemoteLogs,"/data/sophos/%HOSTNAME%/sophos.log"
*.* ?RemoteLogs
& ~
```

Configuration for the local logs :

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Meuh, it works very well, the local log is working again with the ruleset linked to the output, the solution :

```
module(load="imudp") # needs to be done just once
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="remote")

ruleset(name="remote"){
 $template RemoteLogs,"/data/sophos/%HOSTNAME%/sophos.log"
 *.* ?RemoteLogs
}
```